# Is it possible to evaluate a function return is in a list else return a default value?

Tags: python, python-3.6

If I have a function that returns some value and I only want to assign that value if its in an allowed list otherwise use a default.  Assume I can't modify the function.

ie this works, but its calling the function twice.

```
def some_func():
    return 'foo'

allowed_list = ['foo', 'bar']
value = some_func() if some_func() in allowed_list else 'default'
```

is there a pythonic way to set the value in a single line without calling the function twice?

Comment: its easy enough to solve by assigning the function return to a variable first, but I was just curious if there is a way to do it in one line

Comment: You may consider using an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Comment: Ah let me edit my question, unfortunately I'm limited up to python 3.6 and it looks like the assignment expressions came out in 3.8

Comment: In that case, maybe [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) could come in handy.

Comment: its a good idea but won't work in my case as the return from the call can change frequently so caching could be problematic.

Answer (score 4):

From Python **3.8**:

```
value = x if (x:=foo()) in allowed_list else 'default'
```

Comment: I realized I should have edited my question to include the specific python version 3.6. assignment expressions came out in 3.8 so I can't use them :(

Comment: @dranobob Without 3.8, you'll have to use your proposed alternative of assigning to a variable first

Comment: @RyanHaining ok, that's what I'll do then!

Answer (score 1):

If you enjoy doing some overkill to do simple tasks(assignment expressions/walrus operator), define a decorator which takes care of the returned value for you :

```
allowed_list = ['foo', ]

def check_return_value(fn):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return result if result in allowed_list else 'default'

    return inner


# suppose this name is imported from somewhere else and you can't use @ syntax
def some_func():
    return 'boo'

some_func = check_return_value(some_func)

var = some_func()
print(var)  # prints "default"
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're confined to Python 3.6 and can't use assignment expressions, you could make yourself a helper function to handle this.

```
def some_func():
    return 'foo'

def default_if_invalid(value, allowed_values, default):
    return value if value in allowed_values else default

allowed_list = ['foo', 'bar']
value = default_if_invalid(some_func(), allowed_list, 'default')
```

This can be easily modified if, say, you always check against the same list of allowed values, or if you want the method to supply a default default (perhaps `None`) if one isn't provided. For instance:

```
def default_if_invalid(value, default=None):
    allowed_list = ['foo', 'bar']
    return value if value in allowed_values else default

value = default_if_invalid(some_func()) # sets to None if not in list
value = default_if_invalid(some_func(), 'default') # specifies a default
```